# Drag WPF Control into desktop to create new Window

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

In my application I want to drag a particular user control into desktop that creates a new window with the dropped control (Something similar to visual studio 2010 (implemented using wpf) tab items or google chrome tabs). As far as I know we can only drag drop file object to desktop and not the user control. Is there any way to achieve this? is there any control available for this purpose?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Looking for this also. Just want something that can take a tab etc and implement the drag-drop into a new window. My guess would be that each window would actually be a UserControl and hosted in a window. So when you dropped you would simply change hosts to a new window once it's created. Anyone done this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a something similar.  What I did to make this work, was create a new window when my mouse left the original window rather than waiting until the mouse button was released.